# How do i port a php 7 array to php 8?

Tags: wordpress

Got this error using php 7, but need it to work in php 8.

Error is:

“Warning: Undefined array key "sv" on line 226”

Code:

```
 public $active_language = null;
 if(function_exists('pll_languages_list')) {
  foreach(pll_languages_list() as $lang) {
    $this->active_languages[] = [
      "short" => $lang,
      "long" => $this->active_languages[$lang] //226
    ];
  }
}
```

How?

Comment: That's a warning not an error. In PHP 7 it's doing the same thing, except the warning is silent. Maybe try `"long" => isset($this->active_languages[$lang]) ? $this->active_languages[$lang] : null`

Comment: This seems like a typo. Why are you nesting `$this->active_languages[]` with `$this->active_languages[$lang]` ? One way to produce the same results without the warning is to define a default  value of `null` when it does not exist by using the null coalescing operator `"long" => $this->active_languages[$lang] ?? null` Otherwise, best-practice is to ensure the value exists before attempting to add it to the `$this->active_languages[] =` array, like using `if (array_key_exists($lang, $this->active_languages))`.  Example: https://3v4l.org/VHF78